# How do I compile a C++ shared library, load and run it in Python?

Tags: python, c++, binding, shared-libraries

I have a function in C++ that takes a list of sets of integers and merges the sets where there is a common element between sets. The code is lifted from here: [combine pairs of integers based on common element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27466321/combine-pairs-of-integers-based-on-common-element).

My C++ file is called merge_sets.cpp and contains the below code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

std::list<std::set<int>> Merge(std::list<std::set<int>> values){
    for( std::list<std::set<int>>::iterator iter = values.begin(); iter != values.end(); ++iter)
    for(std::list<std::set<int>>::iterator niter(iter); ++niter != values.end();)
        if(std::find_first_of(iter->begin(), iter->end(), niter->begin(), niter->end()) != iter->end())
        {
            iter->insert(niter->begin(), niter->end());
            values.erase(niter);
            niter = iter;
        }
return values;
}

extern "C" {
    std::list<std::set<int>> merge(std::list<std::set<int>> test){
        return Merge(test);
    }
}
```

I'm looking to create a .so shared library file and load this into python using the cdll.LoadLibrary function. I create the .so file with the following commands:

```
g++ -c -fPIC merge_sets.cpp -Wextra -Wall -o merge_sets.o 
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,merge_sets.so -o merge_sets.so merge_sets.o
```

This successfully creates the merge_sets.so shared library. I then attempt to load the library in python as follows:

```
from ctypes import cdll

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("./merge_sets.so")
```

When I try and run the .py script, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\tjs_1\Documents\Git Repos\single-customer-view\testing_python_cpp_bindings.py", line 3, in <module>
    lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("./merge_sets.so")
  File "C:\Users\tjs_1\anaconda3\envs\SCV_env\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 452, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Users\tjs_1\anaconda3\envs\SCV_env\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\tjs_1\Documents\Git Repos\single-customer-view\merge_sets.so' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

I suspect this is a problem with the dependencies in the C++ script, as the code works fine when I turn the merge_sets function into a toy function that takes and integer and returns the same integer, and I remove all the #include statements from the top of script.

EDIT:

If I change the merge_sets to:

```
int Merge(int test){
return test;
}

extern "C" {
    int merge(int test){
        return Merge(test);
    }
}
```

and recompile to merge_sets.so and load using the same Python script, there is no problem at all.

As a test, if I change merge_sets.cpp to:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <list>

int Merge(int test){
    std::list<std::set<int>> values = {{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {8, 3}};
    for( std::list<std::set<int>>::iterator iter = values.begin(); iter != values.end(); ++iter)
    for(std::list<std::set<int>>::iterator niter(iter); ++niter != values.end();)
        if(std::find_first_of(iter->begin(), iter->end(), niter->begin(), niter->end()) != iter->end())
        {
            iter->insert(niter->begin(), niter->end());
            values.erase(niter);
            niter = iter;
        }
return test;
}

extern "C" {
    int merge(int test){
        return Merge(test);
    }
}
```

I get the same error as before.

Comment: Python isn't going to have any idea how to deal with a `std::list` or `std::set`.  You need to limit your interface to C-compatible stuff (numbers, and pointers essentially).

Comment: Yeah I was sure I was going to have to edit this further down the line (e.g. passing and returning an array of ints), but I'm pretty sure the interfacing isn't the issue of this specific error, as when I pass an int and return an int, I get the exact same error.

Comment: `C:` and `.so` seem at odds with each other.  Windows uses `.dll` for dynamic libraries.

Comment: I've added some edits - the .so file seems to work when I implement a more basic C++ function. Am I going about this in the complete wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [python c api](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/index.html). This is an example of a simple extension with a single call.

```cpp
// theExtension.cpp
//
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Primary module for extension.
// 

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Numpy uses a variable PyArray_API to define API methods; this is initialised by calling import_array.
// By default this initialises to a static variable, so is only available in the current module. 
// Defining PY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL indicates that the variable should be not be declared
// as static, so it can be linked to from other .cpp files. Other .cpp files must define NO_IMPORT_ARRAY
// which means PyArray_API is declared as extern, hence it is not defined multiple times.
//

#define PY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL VectorAdd_ARRAY_API
#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_17_API_VERSION

#include <arrayobject.h>

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const char* g_szBasicAdd = ""
"basic_add(output, a, b)                                           \n"
"                                                                  \n"
"Adds two numpy arrays and writes result to output `output = a + b`\n"
"                                                                  \n"
"Returns:                                                          \n"
"- None                                                            \n";
PyObject* basic_add(PyObject*, PyObject* args)
{
    PyObject* pPyA;
    PyObject* pPyB;
    PyObject* pPyO;
    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "OOO", &pPyO, &pPyA, &pPyB)) // object references are borrowed so do not decrement
    {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Failed to parse input parameters.");
        return nullptr;
    }

    PyArrayObject* pPyArrayA = reinterpret_cast<PyArrayObject*>(PyArray_FROM_OTF(pPyA, NPY_DOUBLE, NPY_ARRAY_IN_ARRAY));
    if(pPyArrayA == nullptr)
    {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Failed to cast a.");
        return nullptr;
    }

    size_t iSizeA = static_cast<size_t>(PyArray_SIZE(pPyArrayA));
    const double* pcdA = static_cast<const double*>(PyArray_DATA(pPyArrayA));

    PyArrayObject* pPyArrayB = reinterpret_cast<PyArrayObject*>(PyArray_FROM_OTF(pPyB, NPY_DOUBLE, NPY_ARRAY_IN_ARRAY));
    if(pPyArrayB == nullptr)
    {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Failed to cast b.");
        return nullptr;
    }

    size_t iSizeB = static_cast<size_t>(PyArray_SIZE(pPyArrayB));
    const double* pcdB = static_cast<const double*>(PyArray_DATA(pPyArrayB));

    PyArrayObject* pPyArrayO = reinterpret_cast<PyArrayObject*>(PyArray_FROM_OTF(pPyO, NPY_DOUBLE, NPY_ARRAY_OUT_ARRAY));
    if(pPyArrayO == nullptr)
    {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Failed to cast o.");
        return nullptr;
    }

    size_t iSizeO = static_cast<size_t>(PyArray_SIZE(pPyArrayO));
    double* pdO = static_cast<double*>(PyArray_DATA(pPyArrayO));

    if(iSizeO != iSizeA || iSizeO != iSizeB)
    {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Failed input arrays different sizes.");
        return nullptr;
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < iSizeO; ++i)
    {
        pdO[i] = pcdA[i] + pcdB[i];
    }

    Py_INCREF(Py_None);
    return Py_None;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

static PyMethodDef VectorAdd_Methods[] = {
    // The first property is the name exposed to Python, the second is the C++
    // function name that contains the implementation.
    { "basic_add",   static_cast<PyCFunction>(basic_add), METH_VARARGS, g_szBasicAdd},
    // Terminate the array with an object containing nulls.
    { nullptr, nullptr, 0, nullptr }
};
    
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

static PyModuleDef VectorAdd_Module = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "VectorAdd",                      // Module name to use with Python import statements
    "C++ module demonstrating C Api", // Module description
    0,                                //
    VectorAdd_Methods                 // Structure that defines the methods of the module
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

static bool m_bInitNumpyAPI = false;

void* _initNumpyAPI()
{
    if(!m_bInitNumpyAPI)
    {
        import_array();
        m_bInitNumpyAPI = true;
    }
    return NULL;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_VectorAdd()
{
    _initNumpyAPI();
    return PyModule_Create(&VectorAdd_Module);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

In Windows you can build a DLL in Visual Studio. You will need to add `$(gc-3-10)\include;$(gc-3-10)\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy` to your `Include Directories`, where `$(gc-3-10)` is the directory for your python env; then and `$(gc-3-10)\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\lib;$(gc-3-10)\libs;` to your `Library Directories`, then build with the `Configuration Type` set to `Dynamic Library` an the `Target File Extension` set to `.pyd`; I've never bothered trying to build python extensions with gcc in Windows.

On linux you can build as a shared .so library with gcc something like:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# file: build.sh

(

cd "$(dirname "$0")"

g++-11 -fPIC \
    -I ~/anaconda3/envs/py38/include/python3.8 \
    -I ~/anaconda3/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy \
    -L"$(echo ~/anaconda3/envs/py38/lib)" \
    -shared \
    -o ../Lib/MyLib.so \
    ./theExtension.cpp \
    -lpython3.8 \
    -O3 \
    -std=c++20 \
    -lz
)
```

Once you have built this, add the .so/.pyd directory to PYTHONPATH then you can use it in python something like:

```py
import numpy as np
from VectorAdd import basic_add

a = np.array([1., 2., 3., 4.])
b = np.array([2., 4., 6, 8.])
o = np.zeros(4, dtype=np.float64)

basic_add(o, a, b)
```